# 3D PGFPlots not properly built

Tags: pgfplots

I tried to run a 3D example of PGFPlots gallery http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html and the result is not what I expected.

**My code**

```
\documentclass{standalone} %example 25

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[patch,patch refines=3,
        shader=faceted interp,
        patch type=biquadratic] 
    table[z expr=x^2-y^2]
    {
         x  y
        -2 -2
         2 -2
         2  2
        -2  2
         0 -2
         2  0
         0  2
        -2  0
         0  0
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**This is the expected image:**

[image: exmample 25]

**This is my result:**

[image: my example 25]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I have rendered it in ShareLaTeX and I got the same output as the expected example. What editor and LaTeX distribution are you using?

Comment: @Cragfelt, I am using Miktex and TexnicCenter. I updated all packages and it is still not working.

Comment: This is most likely a (PDF) viewer issue (e.g. it looks like this in SumatraPDF). If you open the PDF with Adobe Reader it should fine, right?

Comment: @Stefan Pinnow,  that's the issue. I was using SumatraPDF and when I opened the pdf file with Adobe Reader it worked as I expected. Do you know why SumatraPDF presents this problem with 3D pgfplots?

Comment: Not exactly. But I already reported this in the [SumatraPDF Tracker](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/595).